# Efficient algorithm to compute the number of points at the lower left of another point

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

Consider $N$ points that are located on a 2D plane where the $i$-th point’s location is denoted as $(x_i, y_i)$.

Is there any efficient algorithm that can compute $d_i$ that is defined as the number of points with $x<x_i$ and $y<y_i$ for all $i$? In other words, we would like to count the number of points on the lower left of point $i$. To simplify, assume there’s no pair of points that have the exact same $x$ and $y$.

By “efficient”, I mean the complexity should be $O(N\log N)$ (in runtime and memory) or better.

EDIT: Adding the specification for the algorithm:
The input to the algorithm is a list of the coordinate of the points (not necessarily sorted in any order) and the output will be a list where the $i$-th element is the number of points in the lower left of the $i$-th points.

Comment: What is the input to the algorithm, and what are the outputs?  Or is this a data structure that is supposed to support several operations, and what are the operations?  (For instance, am I supposed to compute $d_i$ for every $i$, for a single $i$, or something else?)  Please [edit] the question to specify the problem more precisely.

Comment: You might enjoy reading up on the combination of sweepline algorithms, persistent data structures, and self-balancing binary search trees.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/31153033/781723, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/68307/755, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentley%E2%80%93Ottmann_algorithm

Comment: @D.W. thanks for the pointer! The input to the algorithm is a list of the coordinate of the points (not necessarily sorted in any order) and the output will be a list where the $i$-th element is the number of points in the lower left of the $i$-th points.

Comment: Please don't use "EDIT".  Instead, revise the question to read well for someone who encounters it for the first time.  Then, once comments are addressed, flag them as no longer needed.  Don't just append the question - revise it to improve it.  See https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/657/755

Answer (score 2):

Sort the points from left to right. Then scan from left to right, keeping the points met sorted by ordinate in a balanced search tree.

Now every time you insert a new point, the tree contains all points to its left and by finding the insertion point in the tree you obtain the number of lower points.

These two steps each take time $O(n\log n)$. You cannot do better because the solution to this problem would allow you to sort a list of reals $x_i$ by processing the points $(x_i,x_i)$.